# Variable defined and returned but not defined in other function, no global variables (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to define r2 and r1 in their own functions, I've had it return and print it, so I know it's officially in the main(). The problem is when it tries to get the variable in rectangles() it gives an error that r2 is not defined.

My professor instructed us that if you have a variable defined in your base function(outside of the global space) that it would be readable in functions that stem out of the base function.

Is what I'm trying to do simply not feasible or am I just attacking it incorrectly? We are not allowed to use global variables or the global space for our codes. Below is the code I'm trying to run.

```
def f1(x):
    return 5*x**4 + 3*x**3 - 10*x + 2

def rectangles():
    step = (r2-r1)/shapes
    total = 0
    start = step + r1
    for y in range(shapes): 
        res = f1(start)
        start = step + start
        total = total + res*step
    print("The rectangle approximation is " + str(total))

def trapezoids():
    step = (r2-r1)/shapes
    total = 0
    start = r1
    for y in range(shapes):
        m1 = f1(start)
        total = step * (m1+f1(step+start))/2 + total
        start = step + start
    print("The trapezoid approximation is " + str(total))

def r1get():
    ii=True 
    while ii == True:
        r1 = input("Enter the start of the range: ")
        try:
            val = float(r1)
            ii = 0
        except ValueError:
            ii== True
    r1 = float(r1)
    return r1

def r2get():
    ii=True 
    while ii == True:
        r2 = input("Enter the end of the range: ")
        try:
            val = float(r2)
            ii = 0
        except ValueError:
            ii== True
    r2 = float(r2)
    return r2

#def mode():


def numshapes():    
    ii = True
    while ii == True:
        shapes = input("Enter how many shapes you want to use in your approximation: ")
        try:
            val = int(shapes)
            shapes = int(shapes)
            if shapes>=0:
                ii=0
            else:
                ii=True
        except ValueError:
            ii== True
    return shapes

def main():
    #mode()
    #print(mode)
    r1 = r1get()
    r2 = r2get()
    shapes = numshapes()
    rectangles()
    trapezoids()

ma
```

in()

Comment: in order for any function to have access to a variable the variable either needs to be passed as an argument or available in the global scope... so if you are not allowed to use the global scope that only leaves one option.

Comment: You need to pass the variables into the functions, just like how you pass `x` into `f1`. And your r1 and r2 functions are nearly identical. Erase one of them and pass in what you want the input to print, then use that function both times.

Comment: "We are not allowed to use global variables or the global space for our codes." I'd like to point out that you are **defining functions in the global scope**, there is no (sane) way of doing anything without using the global scope at all technically speaking.